# Class file inheritance not a class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class called Item.cpp:

```
class Item{
public:
   int damage;
   Item(int damage);
   int GetDamage();
};

Item::Item(int damage)
{
   this->damage = damage;
}

int Item::GetDamage()
{
   return damage;
}
```

And I want the file Sword.cpp to inherit Item.cpp, like this:

```
class Sword: public Item {

};
```

I get the following error though:
`error not a class name or struct`. I'm confused because Item is clearly a class, so why can I not allow Sword to inherit Item?

Comment: What files does `Sword.cpp` include?

Comment: Nothing, that's the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Sword` to include the declaration of `Item`. Usually in C++, you will have .h (header) files with declarations and then .cpp files with source.

The .h files will be included by anything that needs them; the .cpp files will be given to the compiler (and will pull in the .h files).

**Item.h**

```
#pragma once

class Item {
public:
   int damage;
   Item(int damage);
   int GetDamage();
};
```

**Item.cpp**

```
#include <Item.h>

Item::Item(int damage) {
   this->damage = damage;
}

int Item::GetDamage() {
   return damage;
}
```

**Sword.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Item.h>

class Sword: public Item {
};
```

**Sword.cpp**

```
#include <Sword.h>
```

(so far, empty as far as the code you've provided)

And then you would compile `Item.cpp` and `Sword.cpp`.

Comment: don't forget the include guards (ifndef or pragma once) too in the header. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I needed to use header files too. My Sword file is also empty by the way, the code I posted is exactly what the entire file is, so that little snip wasn't necessary... But thanks again!